# JQuery Accordion Keyboard Accessibility and Disability compliant

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, jquery-ui

I am using the JQuery UI Accordion. We have to make our site 508 disability compliant.  The screen readers will not read the content inside of the jquery accordion some of the time.  It will read the first section if you open it expanded.  It will read the content of the other sections if you click on them.  Or if you arrow down (with up and down arrow) through the headings and select enter, it will read the content.  However, if you use tab and select enter on a heading, it will collapse all headings and the screen reader will read nothing.

I could post my code but this happens when you try out the code on the Jquery UI website.
[JQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/default.html)

Comment: I have tried the dotjay fix.  However, when i apply the header attribute as discribed, it messes up the rendering of the accordion.  http://lab.dotjay.co.uk/tests/jquery-ui-accordion-keyboard-accessibility/

Comment: I am on Jquery version 1.6.2 and UI version 1.8.16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this by setting the focus in the change event of the accordion.  Now, when they change items it will read the contents

```
 $("#accordion").accordion({
    change: function (event, ui) {
        var selectedLoan = '#' + ui.newContent.attr('id');
        $(selectedLoan).focus();
        $(selectedLoan).select();
    },
    collapsible: true
});
```